# How to create right request to Riot API

Tags: python, python-requests, http-status-code-401

So I've been trying valorantpy module that provides an easy way to send requests to get personal player statistics.

This code:

```py
import os
import valorant

KEY = 'key'
client = valorant.Client(KEY, locale="ru-RU", region="eu", route="europe")

account = client.get_user_by_name("SGT ItsRazyHero#VCTRU")
match = account.matchlist().history.find(queueId="competitive")

if match == None:
    print("No Ranked match in recent history!")
    exit(1)
else:
    match = match.get()

for team in match.teams:
    print(f"{team.teamId} Team's Ranks: ")

    players = match.players.get_all(teamId=team.teamId)

    for player in players:
        print(f"\t{player.gameName} - {player.rank}")
```

Checks my latest competitive match and gets information about teammates and their ranks.
So I've got trouble.

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://eu.api.riotgames.com/val/match/v1/matchlists/by-puuid/C3NUBHHFqy-JaV_losaGX0s_-q-NszM5VGYyHHV8GhFMVffm9GhknMFaCiY5GxPLdQ6L_cDYUQol9A?locale=ru-RU
```

And I don't know how to solve this problem.
If you follow this link you will get **401 Unauthorized** error.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a temporary **Development API key**, it won't work cause you are not authorized to fetch match history. You can find a list of accessible APIs that work on a Development API key by logging in to [developer.riotgames.com](https://developer.riotgames.com/) and going to the APIS page.

*Solution:*
You need to register your product and get the **Production API key** or the **Personal API key** (the choice is yours, depending upon your requirements). You can do this by logging in to the above site and registering your product.